# Require that RDP-certificates are installed on the client before logon

Tags: certificate, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I do not know much about RDP-certificates for Windows Server 2012 R2, but I would like to know if it is possible to create a solution where the server is using a certificate in the way that RDP-client needs this certificate in advance in order to try to login at the server. If the client does not have the certificate (in advance) he / she needs to be denied access.

As I have set it up now the client is automatically given the certificate on logon and this means that everyone in the world can try to log on to the server. My point was to hand over the certificate-copies to only the people that should try to log on the server.

Is this possible? Can some one give me a bit of help here? :-) Thank you very much :-)